# Можно ли в suggestView яндекс карт как-либо автоматически устанавливать выбор на первую подсказку в списке?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Поясню, о чем я говорю - допустим, пользователь вводит текст в инпут, к которому привязан suggestView из yandex api. Ему начинают выдаваться подсказки, но если нажать enter, то подсказки просто пропадут, а значение поля не изменится. Но в то же время, если навести мышку на подсказку, или выбрать ее стрелочками, то при нажатии на enter она автоматически выберется.
я попытался сделать некий костыль и отлавливать каждое нажатие клавиш в инпуте и менять значнеие в state у activeIndex. Но это не работало, activeIndex сразу после смены значения заново устанавливается в null. Я решил пойти другим путем и отловить именно enter, сменив значение activeIndex, но и это не сработало, выбор не происходит
я попытался даже стриггерить ивент 'select' после установки значения - все тщетно. Вот примерный код последних моих попыток

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if(e.code === 'Enter') {
    let activeIndex = suggestInput.state.get('activeIndex');
    if (typeof activeIndex !== 'number') {
      suggestInput.state.set('activeIndex', 0);
      suggestInput.events.fire('select')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Если не секрет, в чём вообще проблема? После каждой буквы выбирать подсказку нельзя - они часто неверные и содержимое Input'а нормально ввести не выйдет. А если всё равно надо нажимать Enter, то стрелка "вниз" там рядом - нажать не сложно. Если всё равно нужен визуальный контроль и кнопка для выбора, то какой практический смысл этой доработки?

Comment: Проблема в том, что пожелание это не мое. Я вообще проблемы не вижу в том, чтобы через стрелку выбрать. Но клиент хочет, чтобы при введенном тексте автоматически выбирался первый вариант, если вручную (мышкой или через стрелки) он выбран не был. Не знаю, как понятнее объяснить, что я имею ввиду. Мне не нужно автоматически после каждого символа выбирать его, мне нужно, чтобы он автоматически выбирался, если нажать на ent

Comment: не знаю, где бы взять актуальный пример. Но вот если у этого же suggestView навести курсор на подсказку и нажать enter, то выберется выделенный курсором вариант. Я думал, сделать нечто вроде имитации подобного действия, только с первой подсказкой. Видимо, единственный вариант без костылей, это использовать обычный suggest (который просто объект с вариантами возвращает) и вручную его кастомизировать

Comment: Так-то - да, саджестВью Яндекса действительно ненастраиваемый. Если штатный не нравится, нужно свой создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам эмуляция выбора? Просто получайте значение первой строки саджеста и далее обрабатывайте так, как планировалось. Например копировать в строку инпута:

```
let input = document.getElementById('suggest')

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if(e.code === 'Enter') {
    input.value = suggestView.state.get('items')[0].value
  }
})
```

Comment: Вы не учитываете, что можно вариант выбрать стрелками, но в предложенной вами версии все равно будет выбран первый https://codepen.io/ekubo95/pen/vYavOQK Единственное решение, которое пришло на ум, это смотреть на предыдущее состояние в state.get('activeIndex'), тогда мы можем узнать, был ли стрелками выбран какой-либо вариант, чтобы предотвратить выбор первого в таком случае

Comment: Ну вообще пробел выберет тот вариант, который будет активен, а энтер - да именно первый.

Comment: Если работа на заказ, имейте в виду, саджест без геокодирования и карты с выбранным объектом нарушает условия бесплатного использования и нужен коммерческий ключ. Иначе могут просто заблокировать доступ. Для "чистого" использования подсказок положено использовать Геосаджест - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosuggest/

Comment: спасибо за предупреждение, но ключ у нас приобретен, в codepen просто пример вставлен